# How to properly setup my environment to develop with PHP in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: php, apache2, lamp, ubuntu-22.04

I am a noob on PHP development, and I am trying to properly setup my environment. All I did was install the Lamp stack on my pc (I installed them separately).

The problem is that in Ubuntu the DocumentRoot folder is located in "/var/www/html" which is a root folder, so developing inside it is really troublesome. Then my idea was to change the DocumentRoot folder to a folder like "/home/user/..." but the problem is that I always get the 403 forbidden error, no matter what I do.

Ialready changed the DocumentRoot folder inside apache2.conf, the 000-default.conf, changed the permissions by running chmod and chwon, tried to add a new site inside of sites-available folder, like I did everything I could find online, but I can't get rid of this error.

So I am doing something wrong, should I be able to develop inside the default folder? I know this can be a really noob like question, but I just don't know and couldn't find any other way.

I have some experience developing in Node btw, but never used PHP and apache before, but I need to learn.

Comment: DigitalOcean has a nice wiki with a full guide for most of Linux web distros.

Comment: Also, for distros with systemd you should set `ProtectHome` to `no`, otherwise you won't be able to run any server inside your user home dir.

Comment: And you don't really need to move your website files to your home dir. All you need to do is to add your user to www-data (or whatever group is used by your server) and restart your X session.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, If am not wrong i used the DigitalOcean guide from the start or something like that. Where should i set this ProtectHome to No, insde the Directory tag? and really thanks for your comment, i am really lost right now haha.

Comment: Google "Systemd ProtectHome" and "Systemd config file location". Don't forget to change the user/group of PHP and Apache to your user name after that. At the same time, running a web server inside your home dir is not really mandatory. You can always create a hard symlink from `/var/www/*` to any other directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is One Way (Probably not the best but it works)

You can stick to using **/var/www/html** but whatever folders you decide to use you will need to set the User and Groups correctly.

Out of the box Apache2 uses **owner:group** of **www-data** for both.

In **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** where **APACHE_RUN_USER** and **APACHE_RUN_GROUP** are defined in **/etc/apache2/envvars**

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

So you could change those to suit OR simply add your user to the www-data group... NOTE if you do decide to alter these you will need to restart the apache2 server.

To add your user to the www-data group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER
```

Where $USER will be your currently logged in username. If your user name is "Fred" you can simply type that in place of $USER.
NOTE: You will need to log out and log back in for the change to take effect.

You can check this with the command

```
$ groups
```

which should show your user being in the www-data group.

And then you could go...

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/html/
```

And depending upon your project you'll need to set whatever permissions on your Folders/Files you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but wich is the right way to develop with php in linux? Like i know that in windows you can just install Xampp and put your files inside the DocumentRoot without any problem, but on linux this folder being an root folder is pretty annoying, so should have a better way to do this without this ammount of work

Comment: Well that is what the clown command is for. You can change the owner and group of that folder. Its not written in stone that it shall and must be forever more a root owned folder. You have a key board that lets you say otherwise :)

Comment: Haha, well i just did it and now its working properly, you helped me a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I developed an automatic deployer of a development environment.

Deploys a LAMP server standalone on Ubuntu 22.04. I run it from WSL, I haven't tried it on pure Ubuntu yet:

https://github.com/oajm79/Ubuntu_dev

I hope it helps.